# How can I open an CSV using Python on Mac?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

Ok, this seems to be a really simple question, but I'm really struggling with this. I've read many posts on StackOverflow and in other places, many people have had similar problems, but I couldn't make my code work with the content of other posts. So I decided to look for some help.

I'm trying to open a CSV using Python on a Macbook Air - more specifically, using Jupyter Notebook.

This is my script:

```
import csv

%precision 2

with open("iCloud Drive⁩/Mesa⁩/Mesa⁩/Estudos/Data Science/Applied Data Science with Python Coursera⁩/course1_downloads⁩/mpg.csv") as csvfile:

mpg = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))

mpg[:3]
```

This is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-02dde57740c4> in <module>
  3 get_ipython().run_line_magic('precision', '2')
  4 
----> 5 with open("iCloud Drive⁩/Mesa⁩/Mesa⁩/Estudos/Data Science/Applied Data Science with Python Coursera⁩/course1_downloads⁩/mpg.csv") as csvfile:
6     mpg = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
7 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'iCloud\xa0Drive\u2069/Mesa\u2069/Mesa\u2069/Estudos/Data Science/Applied Data Science with Python Coursera\u2069/course1_downloads\u2069/mpg.csv'
```

What's wrong with the file I used? Why can't I get Jupyter to read it correctly?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `open()` expects a file path, and only a file path. What you've given it is a bash command.

Comment: How did you generate that string? It looks like there are a bunch of extra invisible characters that shouldn't be in there. If you copy/pasted it from somewhere, try typing it out instead.

Comment: Because, apparently, [unicode](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2069/index.htm). Retype your filepath by hand.

Comment: `iCloud Drive` is a synonym. Try using the full path instead `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Mesa⁩/Mesa⁩/Estudos/Data Science/Applied Data Science with Python Coursera⁩/course1_downloads⁩/mpg.csv` or just copy the file to your Desktop and use `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/mpg.csv`

Comment: If you start **Finder** and navigate to your `mpg.csv` file, and drag it to your Python editor and drop it there, it will paste the full path for you.

Answer (score 1):

The path you're passing to "open" doesn't start with a "/" so python is treating it as a relative path. If you want an absolute path, start with a leading "/":

```
with open("/iCloud Drive⁩/Mesa⁩/Mesa⁩/Estudos/Data Science/Applied Data Science with Python Coursera⁩/course1_downloads⁩/mpg.csv") as csvfile:
```